# Java RegEx - special character til end of string

Tags: java, regex, replace

Given rules for Strings are

```
[Random Nr of Letters]##[Random Nr of Letters]#[Random Nr of Letters]##########
```

String Length has to be 35

My String e.g. looks like

```
TEST##TESTING#TEST#################
```

My problem is that I can't detect wrong formats like

```
TEST##TESTING#TEST##A##############
```

My method is:

```
private static boolean test(String test_line) {
    String test = "[A-Z]{1,}##[A-Z]{1,}#[A-Z]{1,}#{1,}";
    Pattern test_pattern = Pattern.compile(test);
    Matcher matcher = test_pattern.matcher(test_line);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

Is there an easy method with RegEx (I have to use it) like "end this String with # and don't allow other characters".

Another problem:
How can I assure that my test won't allow other characters than A-Z 0-9 and #? Something like:

```
    String test = "([^A-Z][^0-9][#])";
    Pattern test_pattern = Pattern.compile(test);
    Matcher matcher = test_pattern.matcher(test_line);
    return matcher.find();
```

(with negotiating)

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You mean this http://regex101.com/r/jV9lQ9/2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets do it step by step:

To ensure that some string has specific length regex can look like

```
^.{35}$
```

where

- `^` represents start of string
- `.` represents any character (beside line separators)
- `{35}` represents how many times previous element (in out case `.` - any character) can appear, so here regex require 35 characters
- `$` represents end of string

In your case you want to only accept characters in range `A-Z` and `#` so you can replace `.` (any character) with this [character-class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[A-Z#]` so your regex can look like

```
^[A-Z#]{35}$
```

But you also want to ensure order of these characters. In other words you also want to check if entire string matches some other regex

```
^[A-Z]{1,}##[A-Z]{1,}#[A-Z]{1,}#{1,}$
```

actually instead of `{1,}` we could simply use `+` which will give us

```
^[A-Z]+##[A-Z]+#[A-Z]+#+$
```

To combine these two regexes you can use [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism which let us peek at characters after position where it was used and check if characters after it matches some additional regex.

So final regex can look like

```
^(?=[A-Z#]{35}$)[A-Z]+##[A-Z]+#[A-Z]+#+$
    ----------- ------------------------
regex1 (length)  regex2 (order)
```

---

Now to avoid recompiling (`Pattern.compile(test)`) the same regex each time your method is called it is better to store its compiled version outside of method as class field. So try maybe something like

```
private static Pattern test_pattern = Pattern
        .compile("^(?=[A-Z#]{35}$)[A-Z]+##[A-Z]+#[A-Z]+#+$");

private static boolean test(String test_line) {
    return test_pattern.matcher(test_line).matches();
}
```

Test

```
System.out.println(test("TEST##TESTING#TEST#################"));//true
System.out.println(test("TEST##TESTING#TEST##A##############"));//false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
[a-zA-Z]+#{2}[a-zA-Z]+#{1}[a-zA-Z]+#{1,}
```

Or

```
^([a-zA-Z]+#{2}[a-zA-Z]+#{1}[a-zA-Z]+#{1,})$
```

Or

```
^(?=.{35}$)([A-Z]+#{2}[A-Z]+#{1}[A-Z]+#{1,})$

TEST##TESTING#TEST################# // pass
TEST##TESTING#TEST##A############## // fail
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kZ9zW6/4)

Comment: `{1,}` is equivalent to just `+`

Comment: @nickb Thanks, I know that :) Just wanted to keep same structure

Comment: @hex494D49 input must be 35 chars long.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks man :) As you can see the OP is editing the question every ten seconds ;)

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match the lines which satisfies the above mentioned criteria,

```
^(?=.{35}$)[A-Z0-9]+##[A-Z0-9]+#[A-Z0-9]+#+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jV9lQ9/3)

It matches the line which contains exactly 35 characters.

Comment: `{1,}` is equivalent to just `+`

Comment: @AvinashRaj +1 Since your comment was a few seconds before my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the format specified ensuring the last character is a `#`:

```
([A-Z]+[#]+){3}
```

To test the length of the string:

```
if(test.length == 35)
    // ...
```

To test and allow digits as well (only alphanumeric and `#` sign):

```
([A-Z0-9]+[#]+){3}
```

To allow lower case letters as well:

```
(\w+#+){3}
```